# Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable and $Y = X^2$.

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, covariance

Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable and $Y = X^2$.

Prove that $E[Y|X] = k$, where $k$ is a constant, implies $Cov(X,Y) = 0$.

Thanks

Comment: If $Y=X^2$ then $\mathbb E(Y\mid X)=X^2=Y$. Don't you mean that $Y$ and $X^2$ have the same distribution?

Comment: Indeed, $E(Y\mid X)=k$ where $k$ is a constant also implies that cov$(X,Y)=42$ and that cov$(X,Y)=\pi$ and...

Answer (score 2):

In this answer, we will show that, whenever we have random variables $X,Y$ s.t. $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]=k$, then their covariance will be zero.

For the answer, I will use the properties of conditional expectation on a random variable. You can view these properties in page 4 in [this link](http://math.arizona.edu/~tgk/464_07/cond_exp.pdf). Using properties in the link I mentioned, we deduce

1. $Cov(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$.
2. $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]]=k$. (properties $(i)$ and $(v)$)
3. $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[XY|X]]=\mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{E}[Y|X]]=\mathbb{E}[kX]=k\mathbb{E}[X]$. (properties $(v)$ and $(vi)$)

Using 1, 2 and 3 we conclude the result.

Answer (score 0):

$$Cov (X,Y)= E(XY)-E(X)(Y)$$
Since X is standard normal then $X^2$ follows chi-square with 1 degrees of freedom.This tells you that E(Y)=1
Using the law of total expectation i.e
$$E[E[Y|X=x]]=E[Y]$$
Since $$XY=X^3$$
and since X is a symmetric random variable the odd expectations are zero.